# Load kernel modulebusing qemu

Tags: linux, mount, kernel-modules, qemu, emulation

I have a kernel module (ko) file that is designed for the aarch64 architecture. I'm currently attempting to use qemu on a non-aarch64 system to utilize this aarch64 kernel module for mounting a specific file system within the non-aarch64 system.

I'm curious if it's possible to load and use this module using qemu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can’t use QEMU to load a foreign-architecture kernel module. Modules have to match the architecture of the kernel they’re loaded into (and its ABI, so you can’t load an arbitrary binary module anyway).

The only way you can load your module is to run a VM using QEMU, with the matching foreign-architecture kernel. That would allow you at least to copy the contents of your specific file system to another volume.